# I have a problem with the following haskell code

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I don't know what is wrong with the code. I have just started coding in Haskell so sorry for the trouble.

```
tobase :: Int -> Int -> [Int]

tobase b x = tobase b (x `quot` b) : [x `mod` b]
tobase b x | x `mod` b == x = [x]
```

```
  Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int]’ with actual type ‘Int’
  In the expression: x `mod` b
  In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘[x `mod` b]’
  In the expression: tobase b (x `quot` b) : [x `mod` b]
```

Comment: The second clause will never fire, since the first pattern will always match.

Comment: The main poblem is that ``tobase b (x `quot` b)`` will generate a *list*, not an `Int` itself, hence the type error.

Comment: Thank you. I concatenated the list and now it works.

Comment: @shubhushanshambhu Can you add your solution as an answer? Then you can accept it so this question appears as ‘solved’.

Answer (score 1):

As Willem has already indicated, the reason for the error is that you are trying to combine values of the wrong type via the "cons" operator (`:`). 
This operator's signature is `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` , not `(:) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`, which is what your call is attempting.

Your `tobase` function returns type `[Int]`, and it's the first argument passed to the `:` operator. Since the type variable `a` in `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` has this `[Int]` type in your invocation, the compiler expects the second argument to be `[[Int]]`. However you are passing in `` [x `mod` b] `` which is of type `[Int]`. 
Instead of using `:` you can use `++` to combine the two lists.

As also noted, the pattern matching order in your function definition should be reversed because the second case `` tobase b x | x `mod` b == x = [x] `` will never be reached. See http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions